# Format DateTime then modify by subtracting formated datetime with minusMinutes() method

Tags: java, java-time

I am quite new to programming and am practicing implementing the Oracle literature. I choose working on time programming and am trying to format and subtract the current time then display a reduced time. My code is

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

class Workingg {
  public static void main(String[] args){

    LocalDateTime datetimeobj = LocalDateTime.now();
    DateTimeFormatter formatobj = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    LocalDateTime newdatetimeobj = datetimeobj.format(formatobj);

    String wasminute = newdatetimeobj.minusMinutes( 2 ).toString();

    System.out.println(wasminute);

  }
}
```

please let me know what i am doing wrong and what is right to format then minus the formatted time. Thanks to those who respond to this.

Comment: You should report the precise error message when posting this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime
.now()
.minusMinutes( 2 )
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss" )
)
```

> format then minus the formatted time

You’ve got that backwards. **Perform your date-time math first**, then generate text.

### Details

> `LocalDateTime newdatetimeobj = datetimeobj.format(formatobj);`

The `format` method returns text, a `String` object. Then you try to assign that string to a variable declared as holding a `LocalDateTime`. **But a `LocalDateTime` is not a `String`.** So your assignment fails, with a compiler error telling about a mismatch in types.

**A date-time object is not text**, so it has no format. A date-time object can generate text representing its value; that is what the `format` method does. But that text does not exist within the date-time object.

By the way, I cannot imagine a case where calling `LocalDateTime.now` would be wise. That class lacks the context of a time zone or offset from UTC. So that class cannot represent a moment, a point on the timeline. Jumping back two minutes via `LocalDateTime` could result in the wrong time for some moments in some time zones.

Instead use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime` to represent a moment.

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now() ; // Capture the current moment as seen in the JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Subtract two minutes.

```
ZonedDateTime twoMinutesEarlier = now.minusMinutes( 2 ) ;
```

#### Generate text

After having performed your date-time math, you can generate text.

Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format, extended wisely to append the name of the time zone in square brackets, by calling `toString`.

Or generate text in your custom format with a `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a `LocalDateTime` object stored on `datetimeobj`, so just apply the `minusMinute` directly to it:

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

class Workingg {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    LocalDateTime datetimeobj = LocalDateTime.now();

    String wasminute = datetimeobj.minusMinutes(2).toString();
    System.out.println(wasminute);
  }
}
```

If you wanted to parse a String, then you would use a `DateTimeFormatter`:

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

class Workingg {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String stringobj = "12-28-2023 17:41:02";
    DateTimeFormatter formatobj = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime datetimeobj = LocalDateTime.parse(stringobj, formatobj);

    String wasminute = datetimeobj.minusMinutes(2).toString();
    System.out.println(wasminute);
  }
}
```

or if you want to output the updated `LocalDateTime` formatted:

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

class Workingg {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    LocalDateTime datetimeobj = LocalDateTime.now();
    DateTimeFormatter formatobj = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    String wasminute = datetimeobj.minusMinutes(2).format(formatobj);
    System.out.println(wasminute);
  }
}
```